# Completion of Power Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be field, char. not equal to two.

Let $A = k[X,Y]/(Y^2 - X^2(X+1))$ with $\mathfrak{m}=(X,Y)$-adic topology. I want to show that $A'$, the completion of $A$, is isomorphic to $k[[U,V]]/(UV)$.

I showed that $A'=k[[X,Y]]/(Y^2 - X^2(X+1))$. Now I need to establish an isomorphism between these two topological rings.

The idea is that $X+1$ has a square root if we use power series, write $X+1 = F(X)^2$ for some formal power series. Factor $Y^2 - X^2(X+1) = (Y - XF(X))(Y+XF(X))$. Now define the map $k[[U,V]]/(UV) \to k[[X,Y]]/(Y^2 - X^2(X+1))$ by sending $U\mapsto Y - XF(X)$ and $V\mapsto Y + XF(X)$. This map is well-defined.

Is there a nice way to see it is surjective? Clearly, $\tfrac{1}{2}(U+V)\mapsto Y$. Next, since $Y^2 = X^2(X+1)$, "solve by radicals", for $X$, and then expand into a power series that radical solution, this way we can realize $X$ as an image of some power series. But is there a nicer method? (Hensel?)

Finally, why is this map injective?